# How to transform JSON into relational data in SQL?

Tags: sql, json

I have a database with a column having JSON data that doesn't have a clear structure. It contains multiple nested tables. This data come from different surveys. I need to use SQL dynamic to automate the process of dividing this data into multiple tables with relational data that can be analysed later with T-SQL.

Do you have any idea how can JSONs that don't have a structure be transformed into relational data?

**This is the logic:**

Source

| ID | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"A":"1","B":{"X":"AAA","Y":"BBB","C":{"AC":"1","BC":"2"}} |

PrincipalTable

| ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

Table1

| B | X | Y | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | BBB | 1 |

Table2

| C | AC | BC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: A relational model needs a clear structure. If, by definition, the data ifself doesn't have a clear structure, then I don't think it can be put in relational form in the first place.

Comment: Can you post samples of the JSON as well as the version of SQL Server you are using? There are JSON functions within SQL Server that can help you do this, but @TheImpaler is correct, if the JSON doesn't have clear structure, it will be difficult.

Comment: Check out [OPENJSON](https://database.guide/introduction-to-openjson-with-examples-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

importJson("{absolute path to JSON file}", {schema: "{schema name}", table: "{table name}", tableColumn: "{column name}"})

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).